# How to set keys and values of a hashmap as tags and values of a xml file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink

I followed http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html and wrote my code as follows

Request and response XML

```
<AlphabetReq>
    <a>Apple</a>
    <b>Ball</b>
    <c>Cat</c> 
    <d>Dog</d>
    <e>Elephant</e>
    <f>Fox</f>
</AlphabetReq>

<AlphabetResp>
    <a>Apple</a>
    <b>Ball</b>
    <c>Cat</c> 
    <d>Dog</d>
    <e>Elephant</e>
    <f>Fox</f>
</AlphabetResp>
```

AlphabetReq and AlphabetResp classes

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Alph {

@XmlPath(".")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AlphAdapter.class)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> cLinkedHashMap = new 
        LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@XmlPath(".")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AlphAdapter.class)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> gLinkedHashMap = new 
        LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

protected void put(String theKey, String theValue) {
    cLinkedHashMap.put(theKey, theValue);   
    gLinkedHashMap.put(theKey, theValue);
}

protected String get(String theKey) {
    return (String) cLinkedHashMap.get(theKey);
}

protected Set<Entry<String,String>> getCEntrySet() {
    return cLinkedHashMap.entrySet();
}

protected Set<Entry<String,String>> getGEntrySet() {
    return gLinkedHashMap.entrySet();
}

protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCLinkedHashMap() {
    return cLinkedHashMap;
}

protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> getGLinkedHashMap() {
    return gLinkedHashMap;
}

public String toCXML() throws XMLHandlingException {
    return null;
}

public String toGXML() throws XMLHandlingException {
    return null;
}

}

@XmlRootElement(name="AlphReq")
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("AlphabetReq")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AlphabetReq extends Alph {

public static AlphabetReq getInstance(String theAlphabetReqXML) throws 
XMLHandlingException {
    return XMLUtils.parseAlphabetReqXML(theAlphabetReqXML);
}

public String toCXML() throws XMLHandlingException {
    return XMLUtils.getAlphabetReqXML(this);
}

}

@XmlRootElement(name="AlphResp")
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("AlphabetResp")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AlphabetResp extends Alph {

public static AlphabetResp getInstance(String theAlphabetRespXML) throws 
XMLHandlingException {
    return XMLUtils.parseAlphabetRespXML(theAlphabetRespXML);
}

public String toCXML() throws XMLHandlingException {
    return XMLUtils.getAlphabetRespXML(this);
}

}
```

I created the following XMLUtil Methods for marshalling and unmarshalling

```
public static String getAlphabetReqXML(Alph theAlphabet) throws XMLHandlingException {

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer writer = null;

try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(byteArrayOutputStream, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    JAXBContext JContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlphabetReq.class); 
    Marshaller JMarshaller = JContext.createMarshaller();
    JMarshaller.marshal(theAlphabet, writer);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String theAlphabetReqXML = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
return theAlphabetReqXML;

}

public static AlphabetReq parseAlphabetReqXML(String theAlphabetReqXML) throws 
XMLHandlingException {

if(null == theAlphabetReqXML) {
    return null;
}
try {
    InputStream IPStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(theAlphabetReqXML.getBytes());
    JAXBContext JContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlphabetReq.class);
    Unmarshaller JUnmarshaller = JContext.createUnmarshaller();
    AlphabetReq alphabetreq = (AlphabetReq) JUnmarshaller.unmarshal(IPStream);
    return alphabetreq;
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static String getAlphabetRespXML(Alph theAlphabet) throws XMLHandlingException {

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer writer = null;

try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(byteArrayOutputStream, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    writer.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    JAXBContext JContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlphabetResp.class); 
    Marshaller JMarshaller = JContext.createMarshaller();
    JMarshaller.marshal(theAlphabet, writer);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String theAlphabetRespXML = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
return theAlphabetRespXML;

}

public static AlphabetResp parseAlphabetReqXML(String theAlphabetRespXML) throws 
XMLHandlingException {

if(null == theAlphabetRespXML) {
    return null;
}
try {
    InputStream IPStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(theAlphabetRespXML.getBytes());
    JAXBContext JContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlphabetResp.class);
    Unmarshaller JUnmarshaller = JContext.createUnmarshaller();
    AlphabetResp alphabetresp = (AlphabetResp) JUnmarshaller.unmarshal(IPStream);
    return alphabetresp;
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and introduced an Adapter class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode;

public class AlphAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AlphAdapter.AdaptedMap, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>{

public static class AdaptedMap {
    @XmlVariableNode("key")
    List<AdaptedEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AdaptedEntry>();  
}

public static class AdaptedEntry {  
    @XmlTransient
    public String key;

    @XmlValue
    public String value;
}

@Override
public AdaptedMap marshal(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) throws Exception {
    AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry = new AdaptedEntry();
        adaptedEntry.key = entry.getKey();
        adaptedEntry.value = entry.getValue();
        adaptedMap.entries.add(adaptedEntry);
    }
    return adaptedMap;
}

@Override
public LinkedHashMap<String, String> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
    List<AdaptedEntry> adaptedEntries = adaptedMap.entries;
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(adaptedEntries.size());
    for(AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : adaptedMap.entries) {
        map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

When I run this I am not getting any values into my adaptedmap. it has keys but values as null

for ex:

- key: A, value: null
- key: B, value: null
- key: C, value: null
- key: D, value: null
- key: E, value: null
- key: F, value: null

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The problem is you are trying to employ the use element name as key trick for two maps at the same level.  This is causing your problem.

```
@XmlPath(".")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AlphAdapter.class)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> cLinkedHashMap = new 
        LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@XmlPath(".")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AlphAdapter.class)
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> gLinkedHashMap = new 
        LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

---

Below is how your stuff currently works

**Demo Code**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AlphabetReq.class, AlphabetResp.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18741690/input.xml");
        AlphabetReq ar = (AlphabetReq) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(ar, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AlphReq xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="AlphabetReq">
   <a/>
   <b/>
   <c/>
   <d/>
   <e/>
   <f/>
   <a>Apple</a>
   <b>Ball</b>
   <c>Cat</c>
   <d>Dog</d>
   <e>Elephant</e>
   <f>Fox</f>
</AlphReq>
```

Comment: Hello @BlaiseDoughan, We need the second linkedhashmap for logging of sensitive data. Is there any way which I can accomplish with two linkedhashmaps. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@XmlAnyElement` instead.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AlphabetReq 
{
   @XmlAnyElement
   private List<Element> allTags = new ArrayList<Element>();

   List<Element> getAllTags()
   {
      return allTags;
   }

   void setAllTags(List<Element> allTags)
   {
      this.allTags = allTags;
   }

   public Map<String, String> getValues()
   {
      final Map<String, String> retVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
      for (Element el : allTags)
      {
         retVal.put(el.getNodeName(), el.getTextContent());
      }
      return retVal;
   }
}
```

method `GetValues()` returns value as expected:

```
{f=Fox, d=Dog, e=Elephant, b=Ball, c=Cat, a=Apple}
```

**example:**

```
  AlphabetReq obj = JAXB.unmarshal(new java.io.File("D:/test.xml"), AlphabetReq.class);
  System.out.println(obj.getValues());
  JAXB.marshal(obj, System.out);
```

Comment: Hello @Ilya, This is not working for me I am getting the same null value result.